# CRM SDK undefined When Using InitializeFromRequest

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Hello I want TO initialize a New Entity Instance From Another Entity Instance in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Using Using Jscript InitializeFromRequest
The error here:

```
if (typeof (SDK) == "undefined")
    {SDK = {__namespace: true}; }
```

It says that SDK is not defined.
 I added the librearias of SDK.SOAP.JS And JQUERYV1.12.4

Comment: Did you add the library to the form libraries? If so, SDK library should be above your library in terms of order.

Comment: yes, I've added the libraries to form level. First jquery.js then soap.js and finally my functions. I am running my function from a button on the ribbon.

Comment: Ok i solved, i just download the libraries from here and works! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594428(v=crm.7).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our scenario we include *sdk rest* and *sdk soap* in the same file

```
if (typeof (SDK) == "undefined")
    {SDK = {__namespace: true}; }
```

Then give us exception `sdk not defined`

We may solve this by making separate files for *sdk rest* and *sdk soap* then include them in our project.